# Wscript.Shell Run doesn't work consistently

Tags: vb6, wsh

I'm trying to run the following bit of code in a vb6 dll:

```
Dim objWSShell As Object
Set objWSShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objWSShell.Run strPath & "test.bat", 0, True
```

The dll process gets hung up.  The batch file will not run, no matter what its contents.  I even tried an empty batch file and it still hung up.  However, if I try this same piece of code, with this change:

```
Dim objWSShell As Object
Set objWSShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objWSShell.Run "calc", 0, True
```

It works fine.  I can't figure out why exe files work and bat files don't.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run cmd.exe and pass your BAT file to it.

```
objWSShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c " & strPath & "test.bat", 0, True
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the shell scripting stuff, you can make things simpler & use the built in `Shell()` function:

```
shell environ$("COMSPEC") & " /C c:\xxx\yyy.bat", vbNormalFocus
```

Ditto for:

```
shell "calc", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: I agree with this, and it can be enhanced using a "Shell and wait" technique if required.  Google should turn up some examples readily.

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038927/vbscript-hangs-when-launching-batch-file-with-wshell-script-run) where batch files couldn't be run directly from `WScript.Shell`, but I didn't have access to modify the VBScript. It turns out there was a registry override on the .bat extension.

While using COMSPEC worked for me, deleting the registry key actually fixed more than just the WScript problem.