# How to run a batch file minimized

Tags: batch-file, minimized

I want to run a batch file in minimized mode by another batch or vbs script. What i tried is:
batch1.bat

```
@echo off  
start /min batch2.bat
```

batch2.bat

```
@echo off  
{my program}  
del /f /q batch1.bat >nul  
del /f /q batch2.bat >nul
```

When I try this everything works perfectly the second batch runs and does it's job but at the end a minimized command prompt window stays which says `the windows can not fond the batch file` and a simple prompt to the path of the batch file as like command prompt shows.

If i use `exit` command instead of this line `del /f /q batch2.bat >nul` from the second batch only then it works as i wish but it is important for my program to delete batch2 after it runs.
My only target is to run batch2 in minimized mode.so is there any help?i also cannot use shortcut to batch here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [open program minimized via command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057448/open-program-minimized-via-command-prompt)

Answer (score 8):

From [this page](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000932.htm):

```
cmd.exe /c start /min YourBatchFile.bat ^& exit
```

When running the command from the Task Scheduler, I had to execute `cmd.exe` as the program and put the rest in as arguments.  Also, `^& exit` did not close the resulting window for me when run from Windows 8's Task Scheduler.  I had to build the `exit` command into my batch file for it to remove the window from the task bar when it was finished.

Comment: You command is wrong. It is missing a `""`, i.e, : `cmd.exe /c start /min 
"" "YourBatchFile.bat"` [open program minimized via command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057448/open-program-minimized-via-command-prompt)

Comment: To all - ensure that you have a space after the first two "" and the "YourBatchFile.bat"

Answer (score 7):

```
@echo off

if not "%1" == "min" start /MIN cmd /c %0 min & exit/b >nul 2>&1

:---rest of batch below this line:
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
{ my program }
DEL "%~f0" /F /Q
```

Comment: no that didn't work. that's showing the same as i did. the cmd windows still stays.

Answer (score 1):

batch2.bat:

```
@echo off
{myprogram}
>autoDelete.bat echo del batch1.bat batch2.bat autoDelete.bat
2>nul autoDelete.bat
```

Comment: i tried it but this time nothing deleted just a new file autoDelete.bat was created and the cmd window was still there minimized.

Answer (score -1):

guys i got my problem solved while surfing on stackoverflow questions. check out the answers of this question you will find the answer.
[.vbs script won't run batch / how to run batch silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221401/vbs-script-wont-run-batch-how-to-run-batch-silently)

```
NirCMD exec hide "Path to Batch File\Batch File.bat"
```

download nircmd from here
Official site: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html