# How do I run a program minimized from Perl on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

I have a Perl script which starts as an ".exe" (along with my main application)

The job of this perlapp is that it queries how long the application has been open (we have floating license and to free up license we close the main application automatically after 120 mins)

During this process the perlapp which runs in the background invokes another application and it's called `system`

All works as fine except that the called application via `system` pops up in the foreground. I want to run it as "minimized". Is this possible?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057448/open-program-minimized-via-command-prompt, http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=63635.0

Answer (score 2):

What you need is not Perl-specific, but actually part of your Windows operating system. In order to start any program minimized on Windows, use the following command.

```
 > start /MIN foo.exe
```

Now to use this from your Perl program via `system` is simple.

```
my $exit_status = system('start /MIN second_application.exe');
```

Note that this does not work if the program was already running.

---

<sup>Source: [tech-recipes.com](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/512/open-a-program-fully-maximized-or-minimized/)</sup>