# How to start Skype minimized using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have Skype set as one of a few programs to start in a batch file, but I would like it to start minimized. The code I currently have is:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone"

start /min Skype.exe
```

Although that should work, Skype still starts maximized. Does anyone know of some way to fix this ?

Comment: Might be missing some quotations. Try the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29427617/5569327

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official Skype FAQ](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA171/can-i-run-skype-for-windows-desktop-from-the-command-line), you can use the `/minimized` option to start Skype minimized.

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" /minimized
```

Other command line arguments include **/nosplash** to prevent a splash screen from appearing when Skype starts, **/shutdown** to stop Skype, and **/secondary** to start a second instance of Skype.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This worked perfectly and /nosplash was not something that I would have thought I wanted, but I did :D.

Comment: @CounterFactual - Happy to help. If my answer provided you with a solution, please click the check mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[Can I run Skype for Windows desktop from the command line ?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA171/can-i-run-skype-for-windows-desktop-from-the-command-line)**

```
@echo off
If Exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Skype\Phone\" (
    CD /D "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Skype\Phone\"
    start "" skype.exe /minimized
) Else (
    CD /D "%ProgramFiles%\Skype\Phone\"
    start "" skype.exe /minimized
)
```

You can also supply the following arguments:

> /nosplash ====>  Do not display splash screen when Skype starts.
>
> /minimized ====>  Skype is minimized to system tray when it starts.
>
> /callto:nameornumber  ====> Call the specified Skype Name or phone number.
>
> /shutdown ====> Close Skype.
>
> /secondary ====> Allows you to start an additional skype.exe instance.

Comment: @CounterFactual You are welcome; but, please read this ==> http://stackoverflow.com/tour