# How to minimize a java program automatically when opening it?

Tags: java, windows, command-line

Let's say I have a java program and I write this to the command line:

```
java javafile.jar
```

Is there anyway to start the java file minimized (somthing similar to `/min` command)? I need to do it through the commands line.

Comment: what kind of application is it? Graphical application? In what framework is it written?

Comment: @bilak It has a GUI and I don't have access to the source code...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23057448/829571

Comment: @assylias won't work. I'll try again

Comment: Are you trying to minimize the GUI's main window ?

Comment: Also I have commandline arguments

Comment: @Arnaud Yes  (charbump)

Comment: What kind of window is it , a `JFrame` ?

Comment: @Arnaud I don't have access to the source code

Comment: @jhamon Comments must be 15 in length so i use some characters to bump it espcially for small answers like "yes" or "no"

Answer (score -1):

try `start /min java javafile.jar`